# Parsing XML - Subtracting values from tags

Tags: linux, xml-parsing, sed, awk, bc

I have the following xml structure in a very large file:

```
<sit>619709.6044;144998.7059;-090372.58119</sit>
<vll>0;0;0</vll>
<cor>255;0;255</cor>
```

How do I subtract the values in the **sit** tag? The tag is comprised of three values separated by **;** Each has to be subtracted from a specific number.

Any unix tool can be used. (awk,sed,bc,etc)

So if that specific number is 1000 for the first value, 100 for the second value and 10 for the third value the result would be:

```
<sit>618709;144898;-090362</sit>
<vll>0;0;0</vll>
<cor>255;0;255</cor>
```

No need to keep the fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -v a=1000 -v b=100 -v c=10 -F "[<;>]" -v OFS=";" -f ./script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
/^<sit>/ && /<\/sit>$/ {
    $0 = "<sit>" format($3, a) OFS format($4, b) OFS format($5, c) "</sit>"
}1

function format(field, var) {
    f = sub(/^-/, "", field)
    return (f == 1 ? "-" : "") sprintf("%06d", int(field-var))
}
```

Results:

```
<sit>618709;144898;-090362</sit>
<vll>0;0;0</vll>
<cor>255;0;255</cor>
```

---

You haven't been entirely clear about how to format your output. It looks like you want your integers padded with up to six leading zeros, regardless of whether they are positive or negative. The above script will do that. If that zero is actually a typo, then this one-liner should suffice:

```
awk -v a=1000 -v b=100 -v c=10 -F "[<;>]" -v OFS=";" '/^<sit>/ && /<\/sit>$/ { $0 = "<sit>" sprintf("%06d",int($3-a)) OFS sprintf("%06d",int($4-b)) OFS sprintf("%06d",int($5-c)) "</sit>" }1' file
```

Results:

```
<sit>618709;144898;-90382</sit>
<vll>0;0;0</vll>
<cor>255;0;255</cor>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted... padding. Sorry for my weak kungfenglish.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
BEGIN{ split("1000 100 10",dec); FS=OFS=";" }
gsub(/<\/?sit>/,"") {
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      $i = int($i - dec[i])
   $0="<sit>" $0 "</sit>"
}
1' file
<sit>618709;144898;-90382</sit>
<vll>0;0;0</vll>
<cor>255;0;255</cor>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl` with the help of the `XML::Twig` parser:

Assuming `xmlfile` with following data:

```
<root>
        <sit>619709.6044;144998.7059;-090372.58119</sit>
        <vll>0;0;0</vll>
        <cor>255;0;255</cor>
</root>
```

and the code of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
use POSIX qw<floor ceil>;

my @substracts = qw<1000 100 10>;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'sit' => sub { 
            my @sit_values = map { $_ < 0 ? ceil $_ : floor $_  } split /;/, $_->text_only;
            for my $i ( 0 .. $#substracts ) { 
                $sit_values[ $i ] -= $substracts[ $i ];
            }   

            $_->set_text( join q|;|, @sit_values );
        }   
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift )->print;
```

Run it like:

```
perl-5.14.2 script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<root>
  <sit>618709;144898;-90382</sit>
  <vll>0;0;0</vll>
  <cor>255;0;255</cor>
</root>
```